# How can I batch rename files with terminal

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

If I have a set of files like:

```
1-3-Image Export-08_s3c1.jpg
```

and I would like to rename the first part to look something like this, by adding and replacing the first part with 'G2_NR2_replicate2':

```
G2_NR2_replicate2_s3c1.jpg
```

How would I batch process this in a terminal?

Comment: Can you tell us how does it look the name for another file? What is different and what remains the same in these filenames?

Answer (score 4):

Run the below `rename` command inside the directory where all the `.jpg` files are located,

```
rename 's/^[^_]*(.*)$/G2_NR2_replicate2\1/' *.jpg
```

It renames all the files which are in the format(*name*),

```
1-3-Image Export-08_s3c1.jpg
1-3-Image Export-08_s3c2.jpg
......
1-3-Image Export-08_s3c1000.jpg
```

to

```
G2_NR2_replicate2_s3c1.jpg
G2_NR2_replicate2_s3c2.jpg
.....
G2_NR2_replicate2_s3c1000.jpg
```

**Explanation:**

`'s/^[^_]*(.*)$/G2_NR2_replicate2\1/'`

1. `rename` command works same as `sed` command.(`s/pattern/replace/`)
2. In the pattern part, we give the pattern as `^[^_]*(.*)$`

   - `^` --> starting point
   - `[^_]*` --> Matches any character except `_` zero or more times. So it matches upto `1-3-Image Export-08` and whaterver character(`s3c1`) comes after this part are catched and stored it into a group which was represented by this pattern `(.*)$`.
   - Now in the replacement part, we place the text given by the op (`G2_NR2_replicate2`) plus the catched group.
3. Finally the `rename` command performs the whole operation.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: @Avinash Raj answer's is better. Use the the `rename` command instead as shown.

Try using `sed` coupled with `for`. See: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bash-bulk-rename-files-4175429502/#post4792222